# Xcode 15 beta 3 - Could not instantiate class named _UIRecessedMaterialView

Tags: ios, uisegmentedcontrol, xcode15

I have an app that loads a xib with a segmented control. If I build it with Xcode 15 beta 3 and launch on a iPad with iPadOS 17 (or on iOS 17 simulator), it crashes with an error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidUnarchiveOperationException', reason: 'Could not instantiate class named _UIRecessedMaterialView because no class named _UIRecessedMaterialView was found; the class needs to be defined in source code or linked in from a library (ensure the class is part of the correct target)'
> First throw call stack:
> (
> 0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007ff80048c88a __exceptionPreprocess + 242
> 1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007ff800057894 objc_exception_throw + 48
> 2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007ff80048c768 -[NSException initWithCoder:] + 0
> 3   UIFoundation                        0x00007ff804a1eb4d UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 352
> 4   UIFoundation                        0x00007ff804a1eebe UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 1233
> 5   UIFoundation                        0x00007ff804a1e9e2 -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 257
> 6   UIKitCore                           0x0000000108c04a9f -[UIView initWithCoder:] + 1327
> 7   UIKitCore                           0x0000000107c32c81 -[UIControl initWithCoder:] + 65
> 8   UIKitCore                           0x0000000107c5a7b3 -[UISegmentedControl initWithCoder:] + 65
> 9   UIFoundation                        0x00007ff804a1ecb4 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 711
> 10  UIFoundation                        0x00007ff804a1e9e2 -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 257
> 11  UIKitCore                           0x000000010801c7cd -[UIRuntimeConnection initWithCoder:] + 125
> 12  UIKitCore                           0x000000010801cbef -[UIRuntimeEventConnection initWithCoder:] + 59
> 13  UIFoundation                        0x00007ff804a1ecb4 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 711
> 14  UIFoundation                        0x00007ff804a1eebe UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 1233
> 15  UIFoundation                        0x00007ff804a1e9e2 -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 257
> 16  UIKitCore                           0x0000000108015a79 -[NSCoder(UIIBDependencyInjectionInternal) _decodeObjectsWithSourceSegueTemplate:creator:sender:forKey:] + 447
> 17  UIKitCore                           0x000000010801877e -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1118
> 18  UIKitCore                           0x000000010801a112 -[NSBundle(UINSBundleAdditions) loadNibNamed:owner:options:] + 139
> 19  CustomSearchBarBug                  0x000000010671830e $s18CustomSearchBarBug11AppDelegateC11application_29didFinishLaunchingWithOptionsSbSo13UIApplicationC_SDySo0m6LaunchL3KeyaypGSgtF + 462
> 20  CustomSearchBarBug                  0x0000000106718687 $s18CustomSearchBarBug11AppDelegateC11application_29didFinishLaunchingWithOptionsSbSo13UIApplicationC_SDySo0m6LaunchL3KeyaypGSgtFTo + 183
> 21  UIKitCore                           0x000000010857a092 -[UIApplication _handleDelegateCallbacksWithOptions:isSuspended:restoreState:] + 297
> 22  UIKitCore                           0x000000010857be6b -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesWithActions:forCanvas:payload:fromOriginatingProcess:] + 4253
> 23  UIKitCore                           0x000000010858196b -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1241
> 24  UIKitCore                           0x00000001078e6780 -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer completeApplicationLaunchWithFBSScene:transitionContext:] + 181
> 25  UIKitCore                           0x000000010857e1dc -[UIApplication _compellApplicationLaunchToCompleteUnconditionally] + 59
> 26  UIKitCore                           0x000000010857e591 -[UIApplication _run] + 936
> 27  UIKitCore                           0x000000010858301a UIApplicationMain + 123
> 28  UIKitCore                           0x000000010764e103 __swift_destroy_boxed_opaque_existential_1Tm + 10851
> 29  CustomSearchBarBug                  0x0000000106718b1b $sSo21UIApplicationDelegateP5UIKitE4mainyyFZ + 123
> 30  CustomSearchBarBug                  0x0000000106718a97 $s18CustomSearchBarBug11AppDelegateC5$mainyyFZ + 39
> 31  CustomSearchBarBug                  0x0000000106718b88 main + 24
> 32  dyld                                0x00000001068a23ee start_sim + 10
> 33  ???                                 0x000000010dfd041f 0x0 + 4529652767
> )
> libc++abi: terminating due to uncaught exception of type NSException

The simplest xib to reproduce the crash is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.iPad.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="22138.1" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch.iPad" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" colorMatched="YES">
    <device id="ipad7_9" orientation="portrait" layout="fullscreen" appearance="light"/>
    <dependencies>
        <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="22113"/>
        <capability name="documents saved in the Xcode 8 format" minToolsVersion="8.0"/>
    </dependencies>
    <objects>
        <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFilesOwner" id="-1" userLabel="File's Owner"/>
        <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="-2" customClass="UIResponder"/>
        <view clipsSubviews="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="63">
            <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="744" height="1133"/>
            <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES"/>
            <subviews>
                <segmentedControl opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" contentHorizontalAlignment="left" contentVerticalAlignment="top" segmentControlStyle="bar" selectedSegmentIndex="0" id="10">
                    <rect key="frame" x="218.5" y="5.5" width="331" height="33"/>
                    <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" flexibleMaxX="YES" flexibleMaxY="YES"/>
                    <segments>
                        <segment title="Item"/>
                        <segment title="Brand"/>
                    </segments>
                    <connections>
                        <action selector="segmentedControlChanged:" destination="-1" eventType="valueChanged" id="25"/>
                    </connections>
                </segmentedControl>
            </subviews>
            <nil key="simulatedStatusBarMetrics"/>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="467.96875" y="146.484375"/>
        </view>
    </objects>
</document>
```

The xib is loaded like this:

`let nibs = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("SegmentedControl", owner: nil, options: nil)`

No crash occurs on iOS 16.3.1.

Is there any fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The crash is resolved in Xcode 15 beta 6

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the issue was due to incorrect Command Line Tools selected for xcodebuild. It was switched to the stable Xcode 14.3, which I've installed on the same machine.

I switched it to Xcode 15 Beta 3 Command Line Tools and the error went away.

Make sure that you've the correct tools selected in the Xcode Settings:
[image: Xcode Command Line tools]

Comment: I also had wrong command line tools, but selecting correct ones didn't resolve the crash.

Answer (score 0):

In my case,
After completely uninstalling the installed XCode15β3 and installing XCdode15β4 again, the problem was resolved.